# Exception thrown when using non-XA datasource in two-phase commit transaction

Tags: java, spring, oracle, websphere

My Websphere application has 3 datsources. Two of them are XA and the other is non-XA.

I have made a Java method transactional by annotating the method with @transactional annotation.

Within the method, 3 tasks are performed. The first one is using one XA datasource to do some update, then the second one uses the non-XA datasource to select a few records and the final task uses another XA datasource to do some update again.

However, an exception is thrown with the following error:

`An illegal attempt to commit a one phase capable resource with existing two phase capable resources`

I want to know why the above error occurs even my application just uses the non-XA to select some data and no commit is required and how I can get rid of the problem if I am not allowed to change the non-XA datasource to XA.

Answer (score 1):

The non-XA resource cannot by default participate in a distributed transaction. So you have the following options:

- Change datasource to XA - you wrote that you cannot do that
- Try to enable [Last Participant Support](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/webui_pme/ui/ueac_laoextensionsettings.html?lang=en) -  Last participant support is an extension to the transaction service that enables a single one-phase resource to participate in a two-phase transaction with one or more two-phase resources.
- Set this (nonXA) datasource to be non transactional, if you don't need transactions for it. It will not be enlisted in the transaction:

> ```
> Select Resources > JDBC > Data sources
> Select the name of the data source that you want to configure.
> Select WebSphere Application Server data source properties from the Additional Properties heading.
> Select Non-transactional data source.
> Click OK.
> ```

- wrap that nonXA call in EJB, and mark it as not supporting transactions.
- Manually manage transaction - don't use container managed transaction, but handle transaction inside your method manually using Transaction API.

Answer (score 0):

when starting the second task, the previous task which does updates on a XA datasource `need to be commit or rolled back` while you are using `@Transaction` annotation the whole tasks automatically go through one transaction so don't use @Transaction annotation and instead of it put each task inside separate transaction